# how to resume the broken video upload on facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, video, upload

I use the following code to upload video,which is not a resumable upload.
How to resume the broken video upload on facebook ?

```
- (void)sendVideo{
    NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph-video.facebook.com/videos?access_token=%@",self.fbAccessToken]];
    self.fbRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl];
    [self.fbRequest setTimeOutSeconds:60];
    self.fbRequest.uploadProgressDelegate = self;
    self.fbRequest.delegate = self;
    self.fbRequest.requestMethod = @"POST";
    [self.fbRequest setPostValue:item.title  forKey:@"name"];
    [self.fbRequest setPostValue:[item customValueForKey:@"status"]   forKey:@"description"];
    [self.fbRequest setFile:item.filePath forKey:@"source"];
    self.fbRequest.tag = RequestStepUpload;
    [self.fbRequest startAsynchronous]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to resume an interrupted upload. Once the connection has been lost, Facebook dumps the temp data received. They only process the video once they receive the entire payload.

The only feedback from Facebook in the upload process is on completion when a JSON object containing a single graph object `id` as reference to your video.

Once the connection is interrupted or broken, you will need to retry.